# Datetime.Tryparseexact in c# return wrong time

Tags: c#-4.0

datetime.tryparseexact in c# return wrong time
Below code returns wrong time, it returns {3/30/2017 7:34:09 PM}

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("March 30, 2017 2:04:09 PM", MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out time)
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `AssumeUniversal`. It will change the time based on your timezone. Use 0, like:

```
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact("March 30, 2017 2:04:09 PM", "MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out time);
```

that will return a date with `Kind == Unspecified`, or use `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal` that will return a date with `Kind == Local`. If you really want `Kind == Utc` then use `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`.

Comment: Thank you, the DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal ended up being the missing piece of the puzzle for me. The .NET documentation uses CultureInfo.InvariantCulture but that was changing the time on me.